# Query hits and custom dimensions in the BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am working with the GoogleAnalytics data in the BigQuery.
I want to output 2 columns: specific event actions (hits) and custom dimension (session based). All that, using Standard SQL. I cannot figure out how to do it correctly. Documentation does not help either. Please help me. This is what I am trying:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT MAX(IF(index=80, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(customDimensions)) AS is_app,
  (SELECT hits.eventInfo.eventAction) AS ea
FROM  
  `table-big-query.105229861.ga_sessions_201711*`, UNNEST(hits) hits
WHERE 
  totals.visits = 1
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '21' and '21'
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) hits
    WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'SomeEventCategory'
  )
```

Comment: Are you getting some error? Or is the output not expected? I think maybe you should add a `where eventinfo.eventAction = 'SomeEventCategory'` in your second select) but other than that the query seems correct.

Comment: Yes, it returns `query: Column name customDimensions is ambiguous at [2:54] `. But, @sco explanation helped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to give your tables and sub-tables names that are not part of the original table schema. Always tell to which table you're referring - when cross joining, you're basically adding new columns (here `h.*` - flattened) - but the old ones (`hits.*` - nested) still exist.
I named ga_sessions_* `t` and use it to refer the cross-join and also the customDimension.

Also: You don't need the legacy sql trick using MAX() for customDimensions anymore. It's a simple sub-query now :)

try:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT  value FROM t.customDimensions where index=80) AS is_app, -- use h.customDimensions if it is hit-scope
  eventInfo.eventAction AS ea
FROM  
  `projectid.dataset.ga_sessions_201711*` t, t.hits h
WHERE 
  totals.visits = 1
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '21' and '21'
  AND h.eventInfo.eventCategory is not null
```

Comment: Actually, I have got one more question. As I understand this is more an implicit way of CROSS JOINING. In that case, what is the key by which two tables are joined? I assume that currently the joining happens in the scope of each unique session?

Comment: Cross joining doesn't need a key - it's all possible row combinations from both tables. Meaning both tables mustn't be NULL.
And because every session is one row in `t`, yes, it's session scope.

Comment: shouldn't the second line read `(SELECT  value FROM h.customDimensions where index=80) AS is_app` ?

Comment: Anyone getting this error: ```Scalar subquery produced more than one element```

Comment: That means your subquery returned more than one value. But a field can only hold one value - so either you feed the output into an `array()` or you `limit 1` within the subquery. If you don't expect more than one value, there's probably something wrong with the data creation process.