# How to convert legacy SQL BigQuery to standard SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I have been trying to convert a legacy SQL BigQuery code to Standard SQL, but I keep getting loads of errors.

Here is the original Legacy SQL:

```
    SELECT t.page_path,
        t.second_page_path,
        t.third_page_path,
        t.fourth_page_path,
        CONCAT(t.page_path,IF(t.second_page_path IS NULL,"","-"),
        IFNULL(t.second_page_path,""),IF(t.third_page_path IS NULL,"","-"),
        IFNULL(t.third_page_path,""),IF(t.fourth_page_path IS NULL,"","-"),
        IFNULL(t.fourth_page_path,"")) AS full_page_journey,
        count(sessionId) AS total_sessions

FROM (

SELECT
     CONCAT(fullVisitorId,"-",STRING(visitStartTime)) AS sessionId,
     hits.hitNumber,
     hits.page.pagePath AS page_path,
     LEAD(hits.page.pagePath) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS second_page_path,
     LEAD(hits.page.pagePath,2) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS third_page_path,
     LEAD(hits.page.pagePath,3) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS fourth_page_path
   FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE( [xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx.ga_sessions_],
TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01'), TIMESTAMP('2017-01-02') )
   WHERE
     hits.type="PAGE"

     ) t
     WHERE t.hits.hitNumber=1
     GROUP BY t.page_path,
              t.second_page_path,
              t.third_page_path,
              t.fourth_page_path,
              full_page_journey
     ORDER BY total_sessions DESC
```

UPDATED (Edited):And here is what I have been able to do so far:

```
    SELECT t.page_path,
        t.second_page_path,
        t.third_page_path,
        t.fourth_page_path,
        CONCAT(t.page_path,IF(t.second_page_path IS NULL,"","-"),
        IFNULL(t.second_page_path,""),IF(t.third_page_path IS NULL,"","-"),
        IFNULL(t.third_page_path,""),IF(t.fourth_page_path IS NULL,"","-"),
        IFNULL(t.fourth_page_path,"")) AS full_page_journey,
        count(sessionId) AS total_sessions

FROM (

SELECT
     CONCAT(fullVisitorId,"-",cast(visitStartTime as string)) AS sessionId,
     hits.hitNumber,
     hits.page.pagePath AS page_path,
     LEAD(hits.page.pagePath) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS second_page_path,
     LEAD(hits.page.pagePath,2) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS third_page_path,
     LEAD(hits.page.pagePath,3) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS fourth_page_path
   FROM
       `xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`,
        UNNEST(hits) AS hits
     WHERE
          _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
          FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -16 DAY))AND 
          FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))AND
          hits.type = 'PAGE' ) AS t
          WHERE t.hits.hitNumber = 1
     GROUP BY t.page_path,
              t.second_page_path,
              t.third_page_path,
              t.fourth_page_path,
              full_page_journey
     ORDER BY total_sessions DESC
```

It will be great if someone can help spot out what is wrong with the syntax.

Some of the errors gotten include:

> Cannot access field hitNumber on a value with type ARRAY
>
> Issues with "_TABLE_SUFFIX" which I read had to do with the wildcard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point, DATE_ADD needs a date but you're giving it a timestamp and the _TABLE_SUFFIX needs a string but you're giving it a date (kind of).

Try using CURRENT_DATE() and FORMAT_DATE around your existing syntax:

```
 FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -16 DAY))
```

This question might be useful for the hitNumber error:

[query-hits-and-custom-dimensions-in-the-bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117541/query-hits-and-custom-dimensions-in-the-bigquery)

Try using CTE rather than a subquery as it makes things clearer and easier to debug.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT
  CONCAT(fullVisitorId,"-",cast(visitStartTime as string)) AS sessionId,
  hits.hitNumber as hitNumber,
  hits.page.pagePath AS page_path,
  LEAD(hits.page.pagePath) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime     
ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS second_page_path, 
LEAD(hits.page.pagePath,2) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime
ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS third_page_path,
  LEAD(hits.page.pagePath,3) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId,
  visitStartTime ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS fourth_page_path
FROM
 `xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -16 DAY))AND 
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))AND
  hits.type = 'PAGE' )

SELECT page_path,
  second_page_path,
  third_page_path,
  fourth_page_path,
  CONCAT(page_path,IF(second_page_path IS NULL,"","-"),
  IFNULL(second_page_path,""),IF(third_page_path IS NULL,"","-"),
  IFNULL(third_page_path,""),IF(fourth_page_path IS NULL,"","-"),
  IFNULL(fourth_page_path,"")) AS full_page_journey,
  count(sessionId) AS total_sessions
FROM CTE
WHERE hitNumber = 1
GROUP BY page_path,
    second_page_path,
    third_page_path,
    fourth_page_path,
    full_page_journey
ORDER BY total_sessions DESC
```